# replicate columns in R

Tags: r, replicate

Let's consider the data set iris.

```
>iris
        Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
    1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
    2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
    3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
```

How can we replicate each of the COLUMNS of this data set 12 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replicate the columns using `rep` and `each` parameter.

```
iris[rep(1:ncol(iris), each = 12)]
```